# how to show custom REST API error messages in javascript client

Tags: javascript, java, rest, swagger

I have Java REST API generated using swagger, in that if client is unauthorized then then i am sending custom error messages in response

```
    public Response collaborationCollabIdDelete(Integer collabId, SecurityContext securityContext, String authBase64String) throws NotFoundException {
    // do some magic!
    ErrorRequestObject erb;
    ArrayList <ErrorRequestObject> erbs = new ArrayList<ErrorRequestObject>();

    if (authBase64String == null)
    {   
        erb = new ErrorRequestObject(); erb.setError("Missing Authorization in Header"); erb.setPath("Header:Authorization"); 
        erb.setProposedSolution("Authorization Header should contain user:pwd:nhPath as Base64 string");
        erbs.add(erb);
    }
    if (erbs.size() == 0)
    {
            //success code here
    }
    else
    {
        return Response.status(400).entity(erbs).build();
    }   
}
```

I call this API using ajax as follows,

```
$.ajax({
            url : URL,
            type : "DELETE",
            dataType : "json",
            contentType : "application/json",
            async : false,
            success : function(result){         
                Response.resolve(result);
                console.log("Response  : " + JSON.stringify(result));
               }
        });
```

now when i call this API with ajax call it without authorization in header it gives me 400 status that is fine as expected but how do i get error object created with java ? can anyone please tell me how do i get this error object at javascript client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url : URL,
        type : "DELETE",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        async : false,
        success : function(result){         
            Response.resolve(result);
            console.log("Response  : " + JSON.stringify(result));
           }, 
        error: function(err) { /* your code here*/})
    });
```

Comment: thanks! Kasabucki for your answer. this worked totally fine for me.

Comment: when i do err.responseJSON[0] i m getting my custom error object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `error` function like

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

Where,

The `jqXHR`object, `textStatus` - a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object as `errorThrown`, if one occurred. So, you can manipulate the `statusCode` and everything from this parameters like,

`jqXHR.status == 400`