# Get error message from API request using Ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am requesting a API that throw an error but I cannot get the error message.

This is how the API return the error:

```
res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
                    status: 500,
                    message: "Error during insertion" + err.message,
                }));
```

This is how I am trying to catch that message.

```
error: function(res) {
                console.log("Error: " + res.message);
                ierror = 1;

        }
```

Any idea how i can do it?

Comment: This one SO might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036199/how-to-show-custom-rest-api-error-messages-in-javascript-client

Comment: try this: error: function(XMLHttpRequest, status, error) {
     console.log("Error: "+ error)
  }

Answer (score 1):

Parse the incoming string into an Object.

```
error: function(res) {
            res = JSON.parse(res)  
            console.log("Error: " + res.message);
            ierror = 1;

    }
```